# How to generate only a specific subset of pages in NuxtJS?

Tags: nuxt.js

We would like to only generate new portions of the site
We are using multiple CMS and one of them has an API limit.
Is there a way in nuxt to only generate what we tell it to, but keep existing pages as they are?

We have to use 2 CMS for the site, one of them has a limit on the amount of times we can hit the API (60 times per minute).

We are using that CMS for blog posts and for content assets (landing pages, webinars etc).
We have roughly 1000 blog posts and about 800 content assets, so we are running into problems.
Is there a way for me to say "hey, these pages have already been built, ignore generating them again and just generate these new pages here"?  The pages won't change, it is just adding new pages.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using SSR with nodejs in the backend?

Comment: Using node, we want to make it a static site since so much of it will never change.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6138#issuecomment-694827890